# detecting changes in a mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have someone else's code and also a db. To understand the code, I want to see that If I run a particular php process, which tables are updated in the db. Something like I start a listner and then carry out the process. After that the listner will show me a list of changes that happened in the database. Is this possible? 
Note: As I understand, mysql TRIGGER does something similar but it is for a specific table and also on trigger adds rows to another table. I just want a change log sort of a thing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use logging - turn it on, run the code, turn it off, then review the log file.

This article talks you through how to do this:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/monitor-all-sql-queries-in-mysql/